# How to bypass cloudflare using Scrapy?

Tags: cloudflare, scrapy

Is there any simple way to bypass cloudflare protection with Scrapy?
I tried [cloudflare-scrape](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape) but it doesn't work for me and still get 403 error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting 403 Error you can follow these guidlines and if you're facing something else let me know the exact error, i will help.

Go to settings.py

Search: `USER_AGENT`

Here you will see the default bot user agent by scrapy.

Replace that default with this:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
```

You will see 503 is no more.

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error is usually related to your userAgent. Try setting your userAgent to some common browser's userAgent (e.g. 'Mozilla').